# Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017] when running MEAN app on HEROKU

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angularjs, heroku, mongoose

I'm writing my second [MEAN](http://www.codersgrid.com/2013/08/06/mean-boilerplate-for-mongodb-express-js-angularjs-and-node-js/) app. The first one was build aggregating the components by hand (I was not aware of [MEAN](http://www.codersgrid.com/2013/08/06/mean-boilerplate-for-mongodb-express-js-angularjs-and-node-js/)) and hosting it at HEROKU; I attempted to use [MONGOOSE](http://mongoosejs.com/) but gave up due to problems connecting with the database at HEROKU - it worked fine on my MAC. This time around it works on my MAC but I'm still having connection problems; I do not want to jettison MONGOOSE. At this point all I have is the vanilla MEAN app built off its zip file, the zip file downloaded from the [MEAN GitHUB repository](https://github.com/linnovate/mean%20/). See below for the logs I get from HEROKU:

```
2013-09-10T01:33:28.045816+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `grunt`
2013-09-10T01:33:29.526090+00:00 app[web.1]: Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task
2013-09-10T01:33:29.567534+00:00 app[web.1]: >> 1 file lint free.
2013-09-10T01:33:29.568809+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-10T01:33:29.568809+00:00 app[web.1]: Running "compass:dist" (compass) task
2013-09-10T01:33:29.573055+00:00 app[web.1]: Warning: You need to have Ruby and Compass installed and in your system PATH for this task to work. More info: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass Used --force, continuing.
2013-09-10T01:33:29.574527+00:00 app[web.1]: Warning: Cannot read property 'stdout' of undefined Used --force, continuing.
2013-09-10T01:33:29.574641+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-10T01:33:29.575774+00:00 app[web.1]: Warning: You need to have Ruby and Compass installed and in your system PATH for this task to work. More info: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass Used --force, continuing.
2013-09-10T01:33:29.574641+00:00 app[web.1]: Running "compass:dev" (compass) task
2013-09-10T01:33:29.576128+00:00 app[web.1]: Running "concurrent:target" (concurrent) task
2013-09-10T01:33:29.576043+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-10T01:33:30.414023+00:00 app[web.1]: Running "nodemon:dev" (nodemon) task
2013-09-10T01:33:30.511082+00:00 app[web.1]: 10 Sep 01:33:30 - [nodemon] v0.7.10
2013-09-10T01:33:30.511537+00:00 app[web.1]: 10 Sep 01:33:30 - [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
2013-09-10T01:33:30.511664+00:00 app[web.1]: 10 Sep 01:33:30 - [nodemon] watching: /app/config
2013-09-10T01:33:30.511664+00:00 app[web.1]: 10 Sep 01:33:30 - [nodemon] watching: /app/app
2013-09-10T01:33:30.536018+00:00 app[web.1]: 10 Sep 01:33:30 - [nodemon] Unable to write to temp directory. If you experience problems with file reloading, ensure /tmp is writable.
2013-09-10T01:33:30.550590+00:00 app[web.1]: debugger listening on port 5858
2013-09-10T01:33:30.578354+00:00 app[web.1]: Running "watch" task
2013-09-10T01:33:30.624330+00:00 app[web.1]: Waiting...10 Sep 01:33:30 - [nodemon] reading ignore list
2013-09-10T01:33:31.152639+00:00 app[web.1]:         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2013-09-10T01:33:31.154862+00:00 app[web.1]:     at null.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:540:74)
2013-09-10T01:33:31.148967+00:00 app[web.1]: Express app started on port 3000
2013-09-10T01:33:31.152143+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-10T01:33:31.152401+00:00 app[web.1]: events.js:72
2013-09-10T01:33:31.154862+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]
2013-09-10T01:33:31.154862+00:00 app[web.1]:     at null.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:140:15)
2013-09-10T01:33:31.154862+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:478:10)
2013-09-10T01:33:31.154862+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
2013-09-10T01:33:31.154862+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

Any comments of suggestions would be much welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any luck with this?  I can't get MEAN to deploy either due to this same error...

Comment: @rodrigo-silveira Let me know  if you find any solution

Answer (score 3):

You need to host MongoDB somewhere. There are a number of MongoDB hosting services, MongoHQ and MongoLab the most popular. I have used MongoHQ with good results although I must admit I haven't stressed my system. You can sign up for the free trial (I think you get 512MB), once you have done that, replace your connection string with (you will get all the details when signing up):

'mongodb://username:password@domain:port/dbName'

Comment: Sorry for failing to include in the description that the HEROKU instance has a MONGOLAB add-on! Interestingly, I'm able to access the MONGOLAB addon from my MAC's command line, but the app is not seeing it.